# Action Language for Foundational UML (ALF) web system

Tags: web-applications, uml, mda

Is it possible to use ALF to model and generate simple information system/web app? Or is it better to use standards like IFML + some other technologies to model and generate it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using ALF for developing business apps is a good idea. ALF is a quite low-level and complex (textual modeling) language that allows specifying classes and procedures (also called *operations* or *activities*) with more than 50(!) different names for different types of procedure steps (*actions*), including various kinds of state change actions and sending/receiving asynchroneous messages (called *signals*).

Its goal was not to capture higher-level business semantics.

However, you may want to try out [Cloudfier](http://cloudfier.com/), which is based on another, simpler textual UML modeling notation, as described in [this blog post](https://modeling-languages.com/business-logic-in-cloudfier-uml/).

Comment: Thank you for quick response. So with ALF it would be difficult or not possible to develop the whole system, but what about certain parts of it? Lets say I have a client-server architecture. Would it be possible to develop just a part of this system using ALF? Server part - DB, data access logic, backend logic or the backend logic of client without UI and then manualy code the rest what could not be done this way? Is it possible to develop some web API, like REST using ALF?

Comment: Business apps are normally developed with the help of an app development  framework. ALF is not like a framework, but rather like a programming language. You'd have to find a framework that is based on ALF (like Cloudfier is based on TextUML).